# Why Mac Terminal remembers two consecutive commands when they are same?

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I started using Mac recently and before I used to work on Ubuntu.

Suppose I run these commands one by one on my terminal:

```
python3 main.py
python3 main2.py
python3 main2.py
python3 main2.py
python3 main2.py
python3 main2.py
python3 main2.py
```

Now suppose I want to run `python main.py` again, so I will click the up key. I will need to click up key only twice on Ubuntu but 7 times on Mac.

If two consecutive commands are same, then terminal should remember only one command instead of remembering two different commands.

How can I make this happen on macOS?

Comment: Just to pedantic, it's not actually mac terminal that is doing this. It's bash, your shell running in the terminal. There are many shells and it's possible and common to replace the default shell with something else like `zsh` and even further to [customize zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) with various scripts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add the HISTCONTROL environment variable to your `.bash_profile`.  In your `.bash_profile` add the following line:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

Close and restart your bash session and the dupes should be gone.  Alternatively, you could just execute that same line and it will take effect for that session (use it to test it out).

---

From the [manual page for `bash`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html)(in Terminal):

> **HISTCONTROL**
>   A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list. If the list of values includes *ignorespace*, lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list. A value of *ignoredups* causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved. A value of *ignoreboth* is shorthand for *ignorespace* and *ignoredups*. A value of *erasedups* causes all previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved. Any value not in the above list is ignored. If **HISTCONTROL** is unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines read by the shell parser are saved on the history list, subject to the value of **HISTIGNORE**. The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the history regardless of the value of **HISTCONTROL**.

Answer (score 4):

### Why does this happen?

MacOS and Ubuntu are configured differently out of the box to handle duplicates in bash's command history. These configurations are stored in a number of so-called "[dot-files](https://medium.com/@webprolific/getting-started-with-dotfiles-43c3602fd789)". These take the form of ~/.bash* as well the system wide /etc/profile. All of these files might be customised to your liking and differentiate between [interactive shells, login shells, remote shells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles) etc. These files are read in a [specific order](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/) and serve specific functions.

### How to get the same behaviour on macOS?

If you want just this one, single customisation of "ignoring exact duplicates of command lines" you may go with something like Allan's answer, i.e. add a single single line to for example your bash_profile file. There is no "the proper way" but countless options.

In case this is not the only customisation for your bash then this *might* be not the best option:

> - [`~/.bash_profile` should be super-simple and just load .profile and .bashrc (in that order)](https://superuser.com/a/789465/766499)
> - ~/.profile has the stuff NOT specifically related to bash, such as environment variables (PATH and friends)
> - ~/.bashrc has anything you'd want at an interactive command line. Command prompt, EDITOR variable, bash aliases for my use
>
> A few other notes:
>
> - Anything that should be available to graphical applications OR to sh (or bash invoked as sh) MUST be in ~/.profile
> - ~/.bashrc must not output anything
> - Anything that should be available only to login shells should go in ~/.profile
> - Ensure that ~/.bash_login does not exist.

That means, when things get more complex it is [good idea](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile) to [spread out](https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashrc.html) the customisations into multiple files, each of them specialised and highly ordered in their contents:

All `exports` may reside in their own file for simplified oversight.

Create a file that is read by bash at the root of your user directory, for example called `.exports` that contains:

```
# Omit duplicates and commands that begin with a space from history.
export HISTCONTROL='ignoreboth';
```

This needs to be "sourced" so that the file is read by bash on interactive startup:

> Sourcing files 
>   If you have a lot of shell configurations, you may want to split them out into several subfiles and use the source builtin to load them from your .bashrc:
>   with adding `source ~/.exports` to it.

Alternatively, to ensure the files actually exist before loading

```
if [ -f ~/.exports ]; then
. ~/.exports
fi
```

The command `. ~/.exports` will source `~/.exports` in the context of the currently running shell.

> This is particularly useful for adding aliases, the separate file makes it easier to re-load them when you make changes.

Comment: How does `.exports` get read (sourced)?

Comment: @fd0, By itself, it doesn't get sourced in macOS. Allan's answer is a proper way to achieve this.

Comment: If the value of `HISTCONTROL` is set in `.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` is sourced in `~/.bash_profile` then there is no need to `export` the `HISTCONTROL` variable. Both an interactive login shell and an interactive shell will have the variable set.

Comment: @fd0 Exactly: *if*. / In case I do not understand: My point was to provide an alt to Allan's simultaneously posted A / & keeping esp _profile but also the rest as clean and tidy as possible because this is for a scenario where lots of options/settings are considered. Is your last point a suggestion to add or meant as a correction as you may perceive the above method as 'wrong'? Now, I read your comment as between mine and Allan's in level of complexity addressed?

Answer (score 1):

To uniqely record every new command is tricky. First you need to add to
`~/.profile` or similar:

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Then you need to add to `~/.bash_logout`:

```
history -a
history -w
```